# Web scraping of website which is reloading on option selection

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests, scrapy

So i am trying scrap CPI report from indian govt website.
here is website https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/pmsver2/reports/report_menu_web.aspx ,
I am using this approach,

1. When we load this website it asks for multiple options to select. after selecting options and then hitting the get data button, we are redirected to report page.
2. Here, i copied my cookie and session details,which i used in below python script to retrieve information. which is working fine.

Now, i want to fully automate this task, which will require

1. Price report -> Daily prices
2. date selection
3. getting data in code ,
   but the issue is, web pages are redirected and even options on selectors are changing, how do i scrap this ?

i have below script where i've given prefecthed cookie & session as param & able to get data.

```
import requests
#from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

# https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx

# report link = https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/Report_daily1_Web_New.aspx
#url = 'https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/Report_daily1_Web_New.aspx'
#url = 'https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/Reportdaily9.aspx'
# "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=n3npgkgb2wpy3sup45ze024y; BNI_persistence=XIlVKPHMyFvRq0HtLj7pmqXxmRx7y7byO_ia3T0PrBLraaAiDz2RxPPPWpXCo2y2SGMfsbBJx4Pe4wWpm_C-OA=="}
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
#ua = UserAgent()9
#"Cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=dkk2h2003kzfamcypczrfaru; BNI_persistence=XIlVKPHMyFvRq0HtLj7pmqXxmRx7y7byO_ia3T0PrBLraaAiDz2RxPPPWpXCo2y2SGMfsbBJx4Pe4wWpm_C-OA==; _ga=GA1.3.654717034.1651138144; _gid=GA1.3.1558736990.1651468427; _gat_gtag_UA_106490103_3=1"
#res = requests.get('https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/Daily_Average_Report_Data_Commoditywise_Percentage_Variation.aspx',headers=head)

head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD i386) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=n3npgkgb2wpy3sup45ze024y; BNI_persistence=XIlVKPHMyFvRq0HtLj7pmqXxmRx7y7byO_ia3T0PrBLraaAiDz2RxPPPWpXCo2y2SGMfsbBJx4Pe4wWpm_C-OA=="}
u = '''https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/Reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx'''
res = requests.get(u,headers=head)
print(res.headers)
print(res.text)
print(res.cookies)  
with open('resp.html','w') as f:
    f.writelines(res.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
#pprint(soup)
tab = soup.find_all('table')
cnt = 1

htab = pd.read_html(res.text)[1]
fn = "data_{0}.xlsx".format(cnt)
htab.to_excel(fn)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where scrapy? =(

Comment: my question is, if you open this website https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/pmsver2/reports/report_menu_web.aspx , it redirects to diff website (location) and there we have to select options (such as price report, date filters etc), now it becomes tricky if we want to automate this task of report extraction because website reloads every time we use selector and if we see network activity there is lot of things going around, how do i automate this whole flow, so that i can get report in csv in the end. thanks

Comment: i saw scrapy but how it'll fit in this i am not sure, this is question, scrapy or anything else, i want data in the end !